# Is there sense in mounting EFI partition at /boot?

Tags: boot, uefi

On EFI boot based Linux systems you mount EFI on /boot/efi, but EFI partitions already contain "EFI" directory. So, could there be sense in mounting EFI directly in /boot (just when there is one Linux installation on the computer)? I'm just curious. :)

Comment: a folder has to be empty to mount a partition. /boot is not an empty folder

Comment: @ravery You are wrong here, it is possible to mount stuff to any directory. If it had any content before the mount, that will be hidden in favour of the mounted file system. It becomes visible after unmounting again.

Comment: @ByteCommander -- well then in the case of a partion that is mounted the whole time the system is running, the folder is effectively empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to configure a Linux installation to mount the ESP at `/boot`; however, there are some significant caveats and issues that make this configuration inadvisable for Ubuntu. Specifically:

- Because the ESP typically mounts at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu, tools may *assume* that it's mounted here, and if you mount it elsewhere, those tools may misbehave. I haven't studied the issue in detail, but I'd be wary of the GRUB configuration tools (if you use GRUB as your boot loader) in this respect.
- The Debian package management system occasionally creates symbolic links when installing files. This can create problems when upgrading kernel packages, which drop files in `/boot`, since the ESP uses FAT, which doesn't support symbolic links.
- With the ESP mounted at `/boot`, your kernels will go in the root directory of the ESP. This will increase the demands for disk space on the ESP. If you plan appropriately (say, with a 500-1000 MB ESP), this will probably be fine; but if you start with a small ESP (like the ~100 MB ESP that was created by default with some versions of Windows), it may be too small to do the job. Also, do you really want your kernels exposed on the ESP, where any other OS with which you dual-boot can mess with them? This could make it harder to recover if another OS misbehaves and deletes files on the ESP. (Of course, when dual-booting there's no absolute protection against such problems, but putting the kernels on the ESP increases their exposure to risk.)
- If you dual-boot with another Linux distribution, and try to mount the ESP as `/boot` for both distributions, you'll end up with both distributions' kernels in the same directory. This could be confusing, both to you and to things like GRUB's configuration scripts and rEFInd's kernel-scanning code.

That said, some distributions encourage mounting the ESP at `/boot`. This practice is common among Arch Linux users. The Freedesktop [Boot Loader Spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/) also encourages mounting the ESP at `/boot` and putting kernels in distribution-specific subdirectories; however, this proposal seems to be going nowhere.

Overall, you're best off leaving the ESP mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu. Yes, the path to reach the boot loader files is a little longer that way, with a doubling of the `efi` pathname component, but that's a minor inconvenience at worst. The drawbacks to mounting the ESP at `/boot` are much more significant.

Answer (score 3):

No. `/boot` has to contain lots of other stuff, like e.g. all your kernel and initrd images, whereas the EFI partition which you are supposed to mount at `/boot/efi` only contains the EFI boot loader configuration.

Also `/boot` files are specific to and maintained by the running OS and not shared for dual boot systems, while the EFI partition is specific to the machine and contains all systems' config.

Furthermore I strongly believe (but don't have a reference at the moment) that e.g. GRUB and the kernel rely on the exact standardized mount point `/boot/efi` for the EFI partition.